# extracting values based on key in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I have text file having two columns: 1) column 1 is in the format yyyy-mm-dd and 2) column 2 is precipitation.

**Objective:** to extract original value of precipitation from column 2 only for month April, May, june, July, and August (4,5,6,7,8).

**Procedure:** Used line.split to extract only mm from yyyy-mm-dd format from column-1.

- made dictionary to get month and precipitation value.
- using for k,v in dct.items() and then using a if statement to extract the corresponding month precipitation value from dictionary

**Problem:** I can successfully print k,v (month and precipitation) from dictionary items. However, when I am using a if statement to extract the specific month's precipitation value, I am getting blank array. I was wondering can I use .append to get precipitation in `(1.8,2.1,3.3)` format.

Code:

```
file1 = open("test.txt","r")

Growing=[]
Intermediate=[]
Dormant=[]

for line in file1:
    line2 = line.split()
    WQ = line2[1]
    month = line2[0].split("-")[1]
    dct1={month:WQ}
    for k,v in dct1.items():
        if (k ==4 or k==5 or k==6 or k==7 or k==8):
            Growing.append(dct1 [k])
    print Growing
```

Comment: you should probably let us see a bit of `test.txt`

Comment: @goncalopp I am presenting the data inside test.txt below:

Comment: 2007-02-12 1.8
2007-05-07 0.98
2007-08-22 1.0
2007-11-08 1.5
2008-02-07 0.97
2008-06-18 2.0
2008-08-06 1.8
2008-12-04 1.1
2009-02-18 1.1
2009-05-28 1.8
2009-08-06 1.2
2009-11-12 2.5
2010-03-02 1.1
2010-06-21 2.8
2010-08-24 1.5
2010-11-10 1.1
2011-02-23 1.1
2011-06-16 1.2
2011-09-13 0.61
2011-11-09 0.82
2012-02-22 1.1
2012-06-18 1.2
2012-08-15 3.2
2012-12-05 1.1
2013-02-21 1.3
2013-05-22 1.3
2013-08-12 1.4
2013-11-12 3.7

Comment: Be aware that `month` and `WQ` are both strings as you have written them here, and yet you are comparing them with integers. (`'4' == 4` will return False)

Comment: @Ajean, What should I do?

Comment: The most minimal change to your code would be to simply wrap the month assignment in an integer cast (`month = int(line2[0].split("-")[1])`), but I would advise you to consider @mdurant's answer using `numpy.loadtxt`.  Look into the docs about it and it will probably help a lot.  Also, for future reference posting small bits of data is best done in your question rather than comments.

Comment: @Ajean Thanks a lot! Yes, I realize that. Next time onwards I would follow your advice.

Comment: @Ajean you are right. I just changed month to int() like you mentioned above and am getting the answer. Thanks for your help! appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

A more obvious structure would be a dictionary of lists:

```
data = collections.defaultdict()
```

and in the loop

```
data.setdefault( month,[]).append( WQ )
```

and then later you can access each month's data by key.

Perhaps an easier way would be to use numpy.loadtxt,

```
map = {'jan':1,'feb':2,'mar':3,'apr':4,'may':5} # and the rest
data = numpy.loadtxt("test.txt",dtype = dtype([('month','S4'),('WQ',float)]))
```

and then select

```
data[data['month']=='apr']['WQ']
```

Comment: incorporated your code data=collections,defaultdict() in my code and tried to print out. got an error saying" data=collections.defaultdict()
NameError: name 'collections' is not defined." code is providing below:

Comment: file1 = open("test.txt","r")

    Growing=[]
    Intermediate=[]
    Dormant=[]

    for line in file1:
        line2 = line.split()
        WQ = line2[1]
        month = line2[0].split("-")[1]
        dct1={month:WQ}
        data=collections.defaultdct1()
        print data

Comment: I think your `dtype` keyword is slightly wonky there ... and also given the data format (poorly posted in a comment above) you'll end up with the year not the month. Just FYI!

Comment: @mdurant Thanks a lot for your help! I used your code using numpy and map. I got an error message saying" NameError: name 'dtype' is not defined". DO I have to import something?

Comment: @mdurant Got the answer by changing to int for month as mentioned by Ajean. However, I really liked your procedure of using numpy. Thank you!